# What is the best way to split a string (possible with complicated regex)? (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

I am creating a recursive js function which basically parses a string. I do not get to choose the syntax of the string, so i can't change that. its delimited by a ", " which works fine, expect when they are in parenthesis, it needs to ignore inside of the parentheses, in this case it needs to split after the parenthesis. Here is an example.

```
String: "h5, h7, (h5, h7, r3)7, h9"
```

And it needs to be transformed into an array of strings that looks like

```
array(
"h5",
"h7",
"(h5, h7, r3)7", 
"h9"
);
```

I know there is probably a way to do it with regex, and I have a very basic regex knowledge, but I can't figure it out. If it helps here is the js code I have.

```
cols = pattern.split(',');// This is where the regex would go.
                $.each(cols, function(index, val){
                val = $.trim(val);
                    var type = "";
                    var ctr = 0;
                    for(ctr = 0; ctr < val.length && isAlpha(val[ctr]); ctr++)
                        type += val[ctr];
                    if(val[0] == "("){
                        open = 1;
                        substr = "";
                        i = 1;
                        for(; i < val.length && open > 0; i++ ){
                            if(val[i] == ")"){
                                open--;
                            }
                            else
                                substr += val[i];
                        }
                    var repeater = val.substr(i);
                    if(isNumeric(repeater)){
                        for(j=0; j < repeater; j++){
                          colLen += updateRow(row, substr, false);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#'+row).append('<a href="" >SE</a>');
                        colLen++;
                    }
                }
               // If it doesn't start with a parenthesis, do print it as usual
```

Obviously there is a lot more code, but that is the relevant part.

Sorry If i formatted it wrong, this is my first question.

Comment: If you ever want to practice regex, I recommend you check http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple brute force methods that work:

**Method 1:** Match the parenthesized portions and temporarily replace the commas inside with something else so you can then split on comma and then put the commas back in the parenthesized pieces.

```
var data = "h5, h7, (h5, h7, r3)7, h9";

var temp = data.replace(/\([^)]+\)/, function(match) {
    return(match.replace(/,/g, "xx!xx"));
});

var splitData = temp.split(/\s*,\s*/);
for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
    splitData[i] = splitData[i].replace(/xx!xx/g, ",");
}

// splitData = ["h5", "h7", "(h5, h7, r3)7", "h9"]
```

**Method 2:** Split the whole string by a  comma and then puts the parenthesized pieces back together again:

```
var data = "h5, h7, (h5, h7, r3)7, h9";

var splitData = data.split(",");
var output = [], pieces, inParen = false;
for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
    temp = splitData[i];
    if (inParen) {
        pieces += "," + temp;
        if (temp.indexOf(")") != -1) {
            inParen = false;
            output.push(pieces);
        }
    } else {
        temp = $.trim(temp);
        if (temp.indexOf("(") != -1) {
            pieces = temp;
            inParen = true;
        } else {
            output.push(temp);
        }
    }
}

// output = ["h5", "h7", "(h5, h7, r3)7", "h9"]
```

You can see both of these work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cs224/

Answer (score 1):

If it weren't for the comma you could use the `.split(',')` function. I guess a separator shouldn't appear unescaped in the string, but if you can't help it then you could use this:

```
[^,]*\([^\)]*\)[^,]*|[^,]+
```

It matches anything in the parentheses (which can have non-comma characters surrounding them) or a continuous set of non-comma characters. It will only match the content separated by the commas and not the commas themselves.

Comment: `split()` really isn't the way to go for this use case.

Comment: This regex worked beautifly, thanks! also i used .match instead of split.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you don't want to use `split()` to do this - instead, you just want to match a regex multiple times. Something like the following regex would work:

```
/\([^)]+\)|[^,]+/
```

(Match either a pair of parens with anything in between, or something that doesn't contain a comma.)

---

```
var re = /\([^)]+\)[^,]*|[^,]+/g;
var items = input_string.match(re);
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: wow that was quick, thanks. Is there any chance you can explain or link to a tutorial that shows how you would do something like that. I'm basically new to javascript regex. which function would i use?

Comment: k thanks, that puts me into an endless loop though somehow, maybe a for loop and terminate it at the length of the string? Also, that regex doesn't seem to work. I was testing it here http://www.regextester.com/

Edit: it does work. My bad, copy paste error.

Comment: This is getting upvotes, but it doesn't seem to actually work.

Comment: Turns out it did not work when there was a number at the end of the parenthesis. Thanks though! I got it.

Comment: Ah, yeah, hadn't noticed that number hiding there. Also edited to use a better `/g` regex.

Comment: When I run this on `"h5, h7, (h5, h7, r3)7, h9"`, I get `["h5"," h7"," (h5"," h7"," r3)7"," h9"]` which is not even close to working.  I don't think this is worth trying to do with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

you can try alternation with *special|normal* ordering, wherein you first try to match the tricky parenthetical substrings, and match normal otherwise:

```
var data = "h5, h7, 9(h5, h7, r3)7, h9";
var myregexp = /([^,]*?\([^)]*\)[^,]*|[^,]+)/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(data);
var result = "spans found:\n";
while (match != null) {
    result += "match:" + RegExp.$1 + '\n';
    match = myregexp.exec(data);
}
alert(result);
```

*edit*: took out `\w+` (alphanumerics) in favor of: `[^,]` (non commas)